# Problem wrapping std::find. Failed to specialize function template

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am trying to create a convenience function `my::find` that wraps the `std::find` for the `std::vector` type. It may be not very useful, but it makes code a bit cleaner. Unfortunately I am not able to make the return type work. See the example:

```
#include <vector>

namespace my {
    template<typename T>
    inline typename std::vector<T>::iterator::type find(const std::vector<T>& vector, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value);
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline bool contains(const std::vector<T>& vector, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value) != vector.end();
    }
}

bool a() {
    std::vector<float> v;
    float a = 0.0f;
    auto found = my::find(v, a);
    return found != v.end();
}

bool b() {
    std::vector<float> v;
    float a = 0.0f;
    return my::contains(v, a);
}
```

I have also created a similar `my::contains` function, which works fine.

When I am trying to use `my::find` I get the error:

```
[x64 msvc v19.16 #1] error C2672: 'my::find': no matching overloaded function found
[x64 msvc v19.16 #1] error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>::iterator::type my::find(const std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,const T &)'
[x64 msvc v19.16 #1] note: With the following template arguments:
[x64 msvc v19.16 #1] note: 'T=float'
```

Here's a godbolt for it: https://godbolt.org/z/ri_xoV

Comment: Note that `std::vector` has more than one template argument. It's much more flexible if you don't specify the container type explicity at all.

Comment: You are right, I will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up something with return type. This should work:

```
#include <vector>

namespace my {
    template<typename T>
    inline typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator find(const std::vector<T>& vector, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value);
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline bool contains(const std::vector<T>& vector, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value) != vector.end();
    }
}

bool a() {
    std::vector<float> v;
    float a = 0.0f;
    auto found = my::find(v, a);
    return found != v.end();
}

bool b() {
    std::vector<float> v;
    float a = 0.0f;
    return my::contains(v, a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using C++14, then this is even better.

```
#include <vector>

namespace my {
    template<typename T>
    inline auto find(const std::vector<T>& vector, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value);
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline bool contains(const std::vector<T>& vector, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value) != vector.end();
    }
}
```

Don't even bother specifying the return type and there will be no errors. Less typing too!

Comment: This will fail for `std::vector`s with more than one template argument (that's not set to the default for its T)